# How to continuously vary transparency?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha-transparency

Suppose we create a colored band in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
dev.new(width=6, height=3)
ggplot(data.frame(20,20)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=0, xmax=100, ymin=0, ymax=50), fill="blue")
```

[image]

I would like to continuously vary the transparency of the band along the y-axis with the alpha value normally distributed:

```
dnorm(y - 25) / 12.5) / dnorm(0)
```

How to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: http://lenkiefer.com/2020/06/25/gradient-shading-with-ggplot2/

Comment: May also be worth noting some [New Features in the R Graphics Engine](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/07/15/new-features-in-the-r-graphics-engine/index.html), including gradient fills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could plot it as a bunch of discrete rectangles where alpha varies with y, according to the function you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
# make this bigger for smaller rects/smoother gradient
n_rects <- 51

dat <- data.frame(y=seq(0, 50, length.out = n_rects))
dat$alpha <- dnorm((dat$y - 25) / 12.5) / dnorm(0)
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_rect(xmin=0, xmax=100, 
            aes(ymin=y, ymax=y+1, alpha=alpha), fill="blue")
```

[image]